# TFS Could not specify workspace when executing tfs get from the outside

Tags: tfs

I'm executing this command from location `E:\app\`

> TFS.exe get "C:\Repo\" /recursive /noprompt /overwrite

in order to load latest changes from tfs to workspace inside `C:\Repo\`

and it's unable to determine workspace

> Could not specify workspace. This can be improved by using the "tf workspaces /collection: TeamProjectCollectionUrl" command.

Unfortunely I cannot get it to work even with this suggested command

```
C:\Repo\>TF.exe workspaces /collection:url/Collection
Collection: http://url:8080/Collection
Workspace   Owner          PC   Comment
-------------- ------------------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------
USER-PC     USER USER      USER-PC
```

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT thanks! and sorry for being late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the `C:\Repo` to the project before running command `tf get C:\Repo` from location `E:\app`. For example, I mapped `$/CMMIProject` to local folder `D:\Workspace\TFS2018\CMMIProject`:

[image]

Then the following command will work:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>tf get D:\Workspace\TFS2018\CMMIProject`